# Customising Matplotlib Subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I've always found matplotlib subplots confusing, and so I was wondering whether somebody could show how to generate the following arrangement of subplots:
[Subplot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqOtb.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [plt.GridSpec](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html) to easily create differently sized subplots.

```
cols = 5   #number of columns in the grid
s    = 2   #width of top right subplot in #cells
w    = 1   #spacing between subplot columns

fig = plt.figure()
gs  = plt.GridSpec(2, cols, figure=fig, wspace=w)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :-s])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, -s:])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, :-s])
```

[image]

Comment: Note you can also do `gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, cols)` with modern matplotlib

Answer (score 1):

@Marc 's answer is fine, but perhaps easier and more flexible is:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[2, 1]})
# if you really don't want 4 axes:
fig.delaxes(axs[1, 1])
```

[image]