# Adding bar plots at the margins of imshow, keeping bars aligned to cells

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes, imshow

I am trying to add a barplot on top of a imshow plot, and another one on the right, with bars aligned to the imshow "cells".

I have tried both using the approach used in this example [adding histograms at the margins of a scatterplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_hist.html)), and using `make_axes_locatable`.

The result that I get is shown in the figure. There are two problems that I can't fix:

1. the real size of the `imshow` plot is smaller than the size of the axis in which I am plotting it in, since I want to keep the matrix aspect ratio, and so the actual plot will be strictly contained in the axis
2. even when this is not a problem (see the top plot), the bars are not aligned with the `imshow` cells.

[image]

This is my code

```
# from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

plt.style.use('dark_background')

m = np.random.rand(25, 200)

# definitions for the axes
left, width = 0.1, 0.65
bottom, height = 0.1, 0.65
spacing = 0.005

rect0 = [left, bottom, width, height]
rect1 = [left, bottom + height + spacing, width, 0.2]
rect2 = [left + width + spacing, bottom, 0.2, height]

# start with a rectangular Figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))

ax0 = plt.axes(rect0)
ax0.tick_params(direction='in', top=True, right=True)
ax1 = plt.axes(rect1)
ax1.tick_params(direction='in', labelbottom=False)
ax2 = plt.axes(rect2)
ax2.tick_params(direction='in', labelleft=False)

ax0.matshow(m, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())

# divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
# cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='95%', pad=0)
ax1.bar(np.arange(m.shape[1]), np.apply_along_axis(scipy.stats.entropy, 0, m))

# divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
# cax = divider.append_axes('bottom', size='95%', pad=0)
ax2.barh(np.arange(m.shape[0]), np.apply_along_axis(scipy.stats.entropy, 1, m), orientation='horizontal')
plt.savefig('/data/l989o/a/so.png')
plt.style.use('default')
```

**EDIT**
Trying to add details to the plot, like axis labels or a colobar, I saw that the general case can be even more complex. I add the code for the more general case of adding other plot elements, along with the code.

One note, I have noticed that I had to invert the barplot on the right, since when using `orientation=horizontal`, the order of bar was the opposite of the one of the rows of the image.

[image]

```
# from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import functools

plt.style.use('dark_background')
m = np.random.rand(58, 226) * 20
# definitions for the axes
left, width = 0.1, 0.65
bottom, height = 0.1, 0.65
spacing = 0.005

rect0 = [left, bottom, width, height]
rect1 = [left, bottom + height + spacing, width, 0.2]
rect2 = [left + width + spacing, bottom, 0.2, height]

# start with a rectangular Figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))

ax0 = plt.axes(rect0)
ax0.tick_params(direction='in', top=True, right=True)
ax1 = plt.axes(rect1)
ax1.tick_params(direction='in', labelbottom=False)
ax2 = plt.axes(rect2)
ax2.tick_params(direction='in', labelleft=False)

t = 10
n = 2
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(None, plt.cm.Set1(range(0, n)), n)
im = ax0.imshow(m > t, cmap=cmap)
ax0.set_xlabel('image')
ax0.set_ylabel('cluster label')

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax0)
cax = divider.append_axes('left', size='1%', pad=1)
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ticks=range(n), cax=cax)
# cbar.set_lim(-0.5, n - 0.5)
cbar.ax.tick_params(length=0)
cbar.set_ticks([0.25, 0.75])
cbar.set_ticklabels([f'<= {t}', f'> {t}'])
cbar.ax.set_title('# cells')

# divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
# cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='95%', pad=0)
def sum_treshold(v, threshold):
    return np.sum(v > threshold)
ax1.bar(np.arange(m.shape[1]), np.apply_along_axis(functools.partial(sum_treshold, threshold=t), 0, m))
ax1.set_xlim([0, m.shape[1]])

# divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
# cax = divider.append_axes('bottom', size='95%', pad=0)
ax2.barh(np.arange(m.shape[0])[::-1], np.apply_along_axis(functools.partial(sum_treshold, threshold=t), 1, m), orientation='horizontal')
ax2.set_ylim([0, m.shape[0]])
plt.savefig('/data/l989o/a/so.png')
plt.style.use('default')
```

**EDIT 2**
Here is an example of what the final output should look like. To obtain that I have done a wild binary search and set hard coded coordinates (which of course work only for the specific data matrix I have and not in general).

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about using gridspec? https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html

Comment: Setting `ax0.aspect('auto')` and joining the respective axes via  `ax1.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax1, ax0); ax2.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax2, ax0)` seems to work. To get an "equal" aspect ratio, you probably could change the figure dimensions. By the way, in `imshow()` you can set `origin='lower'` to have a "regular" y-axis.  You could set the colorbar at the upper right to avoid having to move the other subplots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this will get you the exact layout you want, but maybe some bits here will be helpful.

This answer uses `gridspec` to define the relative ratios of the subplots and `inset_axes` with `transform` to add the colorbar. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65267066/customising-matplotlib-subplots/65270345#65270345) by @Marc is a nice, simple example of how to use `gridspec`, if that part is confusing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np

m = np.random.rand(58, 226) * 20

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8), constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 3)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0:2])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0:2]) 
## can add these if you need to share axes:, sharex = ax1, sharey = ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, -1])

ax1.bar(np.arange(m.shape[1]), np.arange(m.shape[1]))
vals = ax2.imshow(np.random.random((20,10)), cmap='rainbow', aspect='auto') 
## aspect = 'auto' follows the established gridpec space
## default for imshow is equal axis
ax3.barh(np.arange(m.shape[1]), np.arange(m.shape[1]))

cbax2=ax2.inset_axes([1.05,0,0.03,1], transform=ax2.transAxes)
## the inset axes inputs are x,y,width,height
## the transform "anchors" these relative to the ax2 axis
## so here we are saying start at 5% past the ax2 width; start at the bottom of ax2 (y=0);
### make the inset axis 3% as wide as the ax2 axis; and make it 100% as tall as the ax2 axis
cbar2=fig.colorbar(vals, cax=cbax2, format = '%1.2g', orientation='vertical')
```

[image]

**Updated Based on Comments:**
Is this closer to your needed answer?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np
import functools

def sum_treshold(v, threshold):
    return np.sum(v > threshold)

m = np.random.rand(58, 226) * 20
t = 10
n = 2
cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(None, plt.cm.Set1(range(0, n)), n)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8), constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 3)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0:2])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0:2], sharex = ax1, sharey = ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, -1], sharey = ax1)

ax1.bar(np.arange(m.shape[1]), 
        np.apply_along_axis(functools.partial(sum_treshold, threshold=t), 0, m))
ax1.set_xlim([0, m.shape[1]])
im = ax2.imshow(m > t, cmap=cmap)
ax3.barh(np.arange(m.shape[0])[::-1], 
         np.apply_along_axis(functools.partial(sum_treshold, threshold=t), 1, m), 
         orientation='horizontal')
ax3.set_ylim([0, m.shape[0]])


cbax2=ax2.inset_axes([-0.10,0,0.03,1], transform=ax2.transAxes)
cbar2=fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbax2, format = '%1.2g', orientation='vertical')
```

[image]

Comment: First thanks a lot! `GridSpec` is definitely more convenient than specifying the coordinates. Unfortunately your plot does not solve my two issues: 1) I am looking for having one bar for each column and row, and they should be aligned. 2) The aspect ratio of `imshow` should be equal. I'll now edit my answer to contain an example of how the figure should look like.

Comment: @Nisba, thanks for the feedback and updates to the question--I updated my answer, is this closer to what you need? Sorry if I am still misunderstanding!

Comment: Thanks! I get an error in the last line (the colorbar one). But except for that it is perfect! The error is `TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the ``-`` operator, is not supported, use the bitwise_xor, the ``^`` operator, or the logical_xor function instead.`

Comment: @Nisba glad it is mostly working! Is your code a little different in the last line? There is probably some subtle difference in the code or in the variable assignment that's throwing the error

Comment: Nope, I have run it in a new process. Anyway, it seems just a minor problem, I will fix it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

As you already calculate all the dimensions of the axes, you can adapt them to follow the restrictions imposed by the aspect ratio of the image.  You either need to change the height of `ax0` either by changing `height` or by changing the figure height. In case the aspect ratio is wrong in the other way, something similar needs to be done to the width.

To add the colorbar, you either need to reserve some space from the start, or just place it in the empty spot at the top right.

Here is an example, now including space for the colorbar at the left, and the bottom moved to center the plots. The spacing between the subplots now is equalized.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('dark_background')

m = np.random.randn(25, 200).cumsum(axis=0).cumsum(axis=1)
m -= m.min()
m *= 20 / m.max()

# definitions for the axes
left, width = 0.1, 0.65
bottom, height = 0.1, 0.65
spacing = 0.005
width_2 = 0.2
height_1 = 0.2

fig_width, fig_height = 20, 8
aspect_m = m.shape[0] / m.shape[1]
aspect_rect = fig_height * height / (fig_width * width)
if aspect_m < aspect_rect:  # either reduce the fig_height, or reduce adapt rectangle height
    new_height = aspect_m * (fig_width * width) / fig_height
    # optionally increase height_1 and/or increase bottom
    bottom += (height - new_height) / 2
    height = new_height
else:  # similar for the width
    width = fig_height * height / fig_width / aspect_m
    # optionally increase width_2 and/or increase left
rect0 = [left, bottom, width, height]
rect1 = [left, bottom + height + spacing, width, height_1]
rect2 = [left + width + spacing * fig_height / fig_width, bottom, width_2, height]
rectcbar = [left - 0.06, bottom, 0.01, height]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(fig_width, fig_height))

ax0 = plt.axes(rect0)
ax0.tick_params(direction='in', top=True, right=True)
ax1 = plt.axes(rect1)
ax1.tick_params(direction='in', labelbottom=False)
ax2 = plt.axes(rect2)
ax2.tick_params(direction='in', labelleft=False)
cbarax = plt.axes(rectcbar)

t = 10
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['red', 'dodgerblue'])
im = ax0.imshow(m > t, cmap=cmap, origin='lower')
ax0.set_xlabel('image')
ax0.set_ylabel('cluster label')

cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbarax)
cbar.ax.tick_params(length=0)
cbar.set_ticks([0.25, 0.75])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels([f'≤ {t}', f'> {t}'])
cbar.ax.set_title('# cells')

ax1.bar(np.arange(m.shape[1]), np.sum(m > t, axis=0))

ax2.barh(np.arange(m.shape[0]), np.sum(m > t, axis=1))

ax0.set_aspect('equal')
ax1.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax1, ax0)
ax2.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax2, ax0)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]